# Getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte when trying to read string in python script

Tags: python, scripting

Currently I'm trying to get the name of a vertex group on a model in my python script, I assign the name of this vertex group with the following code:

```
cutterproxweight = terraincopy1.vertex_groups.new(name="CUTTER_PROXIMITY")
```

later on in the script I attempt to access it:

```
cweight.vertex_group = cutterproxweight.name
```

when blender gets to this line it throws the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Note that this isn't the only error it throws and it seems to be completely random but all relating to a UnicodeDecodeError, The only thing that changes on the model between the first line and the line that throws the error is that I apply modifiers on the object.
It seems that the modifiers are somehow changing the name values as attempting to read it after just returns random characters. Reading the name before the modifiers returns the correct value though.

I'm not sure why this is happening as it was working fine before, I am using VSCode to write this so maybe it's formatting it some weird way, I've tried creating a reference directly to the vertex group on the object but I get the same issues.

Comment: ah is `cweight` some weight modifier? i tried all weight modifiers and all works. i'm able to assign `cweight.vertex_group = cutterproxweight.name` without errors... which blender version are you using? im on 3.1

Comment: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa7-in-position-3-invalid-start-byte/18082